# How to ignore React-Bootstrap default font?

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am working on a react app and I have just added some react-bootstrap components. Problem is that the default bootstrap fonts have affected all of my text. I only found one solution on the web which recommended to link a css in the entry file and put the font import and css font property there, but that does not change anything for me.
This is the layout of my imports in Index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import App from "./App"
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "./stylesheets/index.css"
```

As advised below, I have the bootstrap import ABOVE the stylesheet import. index.css contains

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap');

  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #7f0b0d;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
```

However, React-bootstrap is still over writing my font style with the ugliest font I have ever seen.

It affects all fonts inside of my BrowserRouter. My Navbar is unaffected as well as my footer. I even tried putting the style at the component level of the Font. Bootstrap still overwrites it.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-moser-pdoq66?file=/src/index.js

Comment: what are you using `reactstrap` or `react-bootstrap`?

Comment: react-bootstrap is what i am using

Comment: I have added a link to a demo sandbox in the answer, check that out

Comment: can you create a codesandbox of your code so that I can take a look at it

Comment: I just added it above.

Comment: I saw the sandbox and it's working fine with "Kanit" font. I don't see any issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import App from "./App"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./stylesheets/index.css"
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

The order of the imports matter, if you have bootstrap imported after your css file then the boostrap styles will override your styles. So, update your imports as shown above.

Here is a link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-heisenberg-wplxi8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: If you don't mind, take a look at the edits I made above. I have it globally linked and I'm not sure how to pick and choose the styles I want to import. The import statement you added above gives me an error so I suppose there is something else I must either install or import. I tried in both my app.js, index.js, and any components as well.

Comment: I checked out the sandbox demo, and I don't understand why mine doesn't behave like the demo. I have edited my question to show you, but I have mine laid out the same way in Index.js. I cannot figure out why mine won't show the same behavior.